# Including foreign shared library when running a binary with qemu

Tags: binary, arm, shared-libraries, qemu

I have a foreign ARM binary I need to run with Qemu.  It relies on an ncurses shared library, `libncurses.so.5`.

I've tried running

```
qemu-arm   -L /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ ./program
```

Which complains that it can't find `libncurses.so.5`.  I have the correct ncurses shared lib and added it to `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/`.  The filename is `libncurses.so.5` and I have it symlinked to `libncurses.so` as well but running the program still fails.

```
program: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I get qemu to use this external shared library?

Comment: Run it with QEMU_STRACE=1 and QEMU should print out all the calls the guest program makes, including the ones made by the dynamic linker, so you should be able to find out exactly what filename it tries to open there

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that works on the x86 host and fails on QEMU arm?